# Javascript Regex: Get HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, tags

I made this regex:

```
/\<+[a-zA-Z0-9\=\"\s]+\>+.+\<\/+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\>/gi
```

which matches a full html tag like:

```
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
```

But the problem with this that that it matches all of the elements as one match

```
<div><p>this is a paragraph</p></div>
```

But I would like to get all of the HTML elements separated.

Note: The HTML tags are in a string not in the DOM.

Before the regex solution I tried to create a new `div` element and I added the string as it's innerHTML. But doesn't worked properly I don't really know why...

So I'm looking for a REGEX solution which solves this one match problem.

Thanks

Comment: Show your `innerHTML` attempt.

Comment: I thought that somebody will ask me for it :D But I'm really curious how my current question can be figured out :)

Comment: you can't parse HTML [with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).  Using the browser's existing parser through `innerHTML` (or some similar mechanism) is actually the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the inner `+.+` with `+[^<]+` would prevent it from matching the whole string, but regular expressions are not the correct choice for processing strings that contain nested components. For that you should be using a parser.

Regular expressions are simply the wrong tool for the job here.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not appropriate to handle html. As you mention that the HTML is not part of the DOM

> Note: The HTML tags are in a string
>   not in the DOM.

You can use JQuery to build an object from the HTML and use DOM selectors / traversion to work with it:

```
$(myHTMLString).find('p')...
```